# Segmentation fault when assigning int to element of array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, segmentation-fault

This segment of my program is intended to iterate through `char`s of a string, and select all of the numbers in the string and place them in an array called `helper`. This is a small part of a larger program I am working on, I have tried my best to only give the useful segments of code. I am also aware of how a segmentation fault occurs from not using pointer correctly, however my problem is that I can't find where am I using a pointer incorrectly.

So, I am getting a *Segmentation fault (core dumped)* when I attempt to compile the following code...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *eq = "y=344+99";
    int helper[50];
    unsigned short int helperWriter = 0, i;

    for (i = 0; i < eq[i]; i++) //
    {
        if (isdigit(eq[i]))
        {
            unsigned short int d;
            for (d = i; eq[d]; d++)
            {

                if (isdigit(eq[d]))
                {
                    int temp = atoi(eq[d]);
                    helper[helperWriter] = temp;
                    printf("%d", helperWriter);
                }
                helperWriter++; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to C and in turn, new to pointers, so my mistake may be pretty dumb. If any extra info is needed please ask.

Comment: Try `for (d = i; equation.eq[d]; d++)`, otherwise you'll have an infinite loop, finally going out of bounds

Comment: @JVApen This didn't solve the problem, however thankyou for saving me future struggles in trying to find the solution to my infinite loop problem :D

Comment: How large is `helpWriter` when you do this assignment?

Comment: @JVApen just put a printf("%d", helperWriter); statement under the assignment but the program crashed before it could get to it. So I assume 0. I'd be happy to post the entire header file if that would help.

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve]

Comment: Test the index *before* you use it, and put a `newline` at the end of the message. `if(helpwriter >= 50) { printf("index o/range\n"); }`

Comment: @Olaf I have re-written the code to be independent of my project, please inform me of any errors or improvements I can make to this questions, thank you.

Comment: In your edit `for (i = 0; i < eq[i]; i++)` is wrong.

Comment: @TristanArthur: It's your job to do that. We're here to answer concrete programming questions. People should have at least some respect for that and try to be polite to us by writing real question. *Why isn't this code working?* is definitively not a concrete (or real) question.

Comment: @WeatherVane I implemented the code you suggested however  the printf statement does not occur, leading me to believe that helperwriter is not going out of range, thankyou for the suggestion and help though.

Comment: The compiler generates several warnings: follow them up.

Comment: @TristanArthur: BTW, the `[segmentation-fault]` tag, which you tagged your question with, says in its wiki that: `Segmentation faults occur when accessing memory which does not belong to your process. They are typically the result of an incorrect use of pointers or a buffer overflow.`.

Comment: This is the line with error: `int temp = atoi(eq[d]);` it will cause a segfault because you ignored the warning.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question to describe what the program *should do* in your opinion. To me, this is not entirely clear from the code. Especially the upper bound of the first `for` look looks suspicious.

Comment: @KemyLand The question is phrased horribly however if it is any consolation I am more looking to gain more knowledge of pointers and C in general than asking people to write my code for me. As I am fairly new to Stack Overflow, C and programming, you are more than welcome to criticize my working.

Comment: ... it didn't warn you? Surely it warned you about the lacking prototype for `atoi`, which is in `stdlib.h`?

Comment: @TristanArthur: I know, and I'm sorry if I somehow offended/insulted you. However, SO is not a learning-to-program site. There are certain rules that questions **must** follow. Going against them is not only unacceptable and offending to us, but is a quite common routine. I usually vote to close 2 or 3 of each group of 4 questions in the `[c]`, `[c++]` and `[python]` tags. People rarely come here understanding how stuff works, even given the **giant** warnings about how to ask a good question, and the uncountable links to the help center.

Comment: @WeatherVane No I'm not getting any warning when compiling the above code.

Comment: As you say in your edit, you're willing to get everything cleaned up. That's good! First of all, we need an actual question, that is, not "why isn't this code working?", but rather something like "after debugging, I found out this line to cause unexpected behavior on certain circumstances. I've been able to fix the problem, however, what was wrong with that line?".

Comment: In my MSVC setup warnings are enabled by default. I understand gcc has a switch to enable warnings (perhaps -Wall), but I don't use gcc.

Comment: @TristanArthur: What compiler are you using? If it didn't warned you about absolutely nothing, you should be changing compiler right away. BTW, If you're getting into Linux/Unix/Mac-land, or just doing away with MinGW, Clang has better and more descriptive error messages than GCC.

Comment: @KemyLand No I am not at all offended or insulted, and I completely understand your frustration and am sorry for causing so. However please excuse my lack of understanding of the sites nature and rules. I also understand how you may be interpreting these messages as condescending and rude. I am more than happy for any criticism to be thrown my way and I thank you for informing me of my mistakes :D

Comment: @KemyLand I am using GCC on Ubuntu as I'm fairly new to linux, I have the exact code above and I am typing in gcc test.c -o Test. No errors have been given.

Comment: Please see the C info page! **Always** enable _at least_ the recommended warnings (I'd use some more) and pay heed to them! And never use pre-C99 for new code.

Comment: @TristanArthur: Oh, so you're using good, old, and *way too old* GCC? That's good if you know how to get along with the beast. Namely, instead of `gcc foo.c -o bar`, type `gcc -Wall -Werror`. `-Wall` will throw in all warnings, and `-Werror` will make all warnings to be errors, so you don't get lazy about them.

Comment: @KemyLand This really helps, so should I be working towards eliminating all warnings?

Comment: @KemyLand "... way too old GCC" - stop trolling!

Comment: @Olaf I am using GCC 4.8.4 thats not too old is it? I believe it is up to GCC 5.x.x now.

Comment: @TristanArthur: I didn't mean that GCC should not be used, or that your GCC version may be old, or that "being old is bad", but that special care must be taken with it.

Comment: @TristanArthur: I don*t see where you stated that before, so the post is just bashing gcc in general. Anyway, 4.8 is a bit older, but still maintained (iirc, current is 4.8.5) and ok if you don't use some C11 features (namely atomics).

Comment: @Olaf: I'm not trolling, sorry if you took it that way (see the comment above). However, [GCC's first release was on March 22nd, 1987](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/History), as one of the first GNU programs. That's not exactly new...

Comment: @KemyLand: You to call it correctly. But this is true for all compilers. Don't mix IDE and compiler!

Comment: @Olaf: What do you mean? I never talked about IDEs, and they're irrelevant here.

Comment: @Olaf Yeah, I'm sorry about this whole "fail" of a question, now I know to reference what version of GCC I'm using as it may be a factor. Through all this though I believe I have learnt quite a bit about stack overflow, C and pointers though. So overall it has been a good experience for me, however a frustrating one for everyone else :D

Comment: @KemyLand: gcc has been completely rewritten multiple times. Actually, the current one is not directly in-line with the original gcc, but the egcs "fork" with major modifications. May I recommend to read about the history of gcc? Btw. "way too old" is very well prejorative. "There are two kinds of stupids: one, who says 'this is old, this is good' - the other states 'this is new, this is better'"

Comment: @Olaf: I think you got this too personally, didn't you? I never said any of those "stupid phrases". I've read about the EGCS fork, the "Linux C library", blah, blah... However, I'm not sure if those can be considered as "rewrites" in any way.

Comment: @Olaf: Besides, when I say that "GCC is old", I'm talking about GCC in terms of what you expect from GCC, not GCC as a code-base, in the same way that GNU nano can be considered the exact same thing as pico in terms of interfaces. However, both projects' philosophies and codebases are completely different. This would make Clang the same as GCC in some way, and Clang is good, so why would I call GCC bad?

Comment: @KemyLand: "... what you expect ..:" - well I expect it to compile valid C code and provide some of its appreciated extensions (if allowed to be used). And that's what it does. **Your** expectations, however, may vary. It's always bad to project ones own expecations onto others.

Comment: @Olaf: It's even worse to blame on people with random quotes you didn't wrote and/or don't truly understand their meaning. I don't know of anyone using GCC extensions these days... Stallman made it pretty clear that GCC would be monolithic to avoid "proprietary extensions". A bad move, of course, but he did it. BTW, let's better off stop this discussion here. It's providing nothing useful to anyone here. I won't answer to any future comments on the topic.

Comment: @KemyLand: 1) It would be more unfair to blame you for statments **I** wrote. If you don't like to be criticised for your statments, don't write them. 2) This is ridiculous Either I cannot make clear what I mean or you don't (want to) understand; I'm out of this nonsense. 3) Sorry for feeding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a library function without including its prototype, the compiler makes the assumption that its arguments and return type are `int`. You did not `#include <stdlib.h>` (or `ctype.h` for that matter) so in this line

```
int temp = atoi(eq[d]);
```

you are passing a `char` which the compiler happily promotes to `int`. But `atoi` needs a `char*` type. So it tries to access memory at a low address in the machine, causing a segfault. The line should be

```
int temp = atoi(eq + d);    // or `atoi(&eq[d])`
```

which passes the *address* of each string character to `atoi`.

The first loop is incorrect, you should test for `nul` terminator.

You also have an error with `helperWriter++;` being in the wrong place: move it to just below where you put `temp` into the array.

You also ignored my advice to put a `newline` at the end of every debugging message (to ensure it is actually seen before the crash happens).

There are possibly other errors in the way you are picking up the number and then moving past it. You don't need two nested loops, `atoi` will convert the number up to the next non-digit character.

Comment: Thank you, I will be working hard to implement all these fixes, now that I know how to show warnings and errors when compiling I shouldn't need to ask dumb questions. I am extremely sorry to all especially, Weather Vane and Kemy Land, for them having to be patient and dumb down things for me. I have learnt many things from this "fail" of a question and am hoping to not be as big a burden as I have been on the community today when answering and asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

Since the problems in your code have been pointed by @Weather Vane, I want to show you an alternative solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>          /* printf */
#include <string.h>         /* strcspn */
#include <stdlib.h>         /* strtol */

int main(void)
{
    char *eq = "y=344+99", *ptr = eq;
    int helper[50];
    size_t i = 0;
    while(*ptr) // Is there any more numbers in the string?
    {
        ptr += strcspn(ptr, "1234567890"); // Move ptr to the next number
        helper[i++] = strtol(ptr, &ptr, 10);
        printf("%d\n", helper[i - 1]);
    }
}
```

Although this code seems a little more complicated, it's more compact, and it takes advantage of library functions, making it more efficient.

Comment: Even though I don't know about a lot of the functions your using, I will definitely research what they do. Thanks for the alternative solution, works perfectly.

Comment: @TristanArthur Don't worry if you can't understand this, everyone starts from a beginner:)